# Riddle: What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My neck it extends and sometimes it bends
down into the water or up to the sky.

In cities many consider me friends.
With long slender legs, so graceful am I.

Hint:

> One bearing my name is known to have fled from a man with no head

Comment: This might possibly be too broad, at first glance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a

> Crane

My neck it extends and sometimes it bends down into the water or up to the sky.

> Referring to the animal, I would guess, drinking/fishing or flying.

In cities many consider me friends. With long slender legs, so graceful am I.

> In cities you could mean the other kind of crane. "Long slender legs" is likely still the bird, which could also be described as graceful.

The hint refers to

> Ichabod

Comment: Yikes! Ninja'd by one minute because I included explanation as well :-)

Comment: yeah, that was your mistake grasshopper ;)

Comment: Yay! Good job figuring out the hint as well!

Comment: Now I feel bad. I don't mind if you give him the answer for doing it proper. I'll at least give him an upvote.

Comment: @user1566694 No worries. I've often done that trick too - posting a minimal answer first and then shadow-editing in an explanation. And you clearly need the rep more than I do ;-)

Answer (score 4):

How about

> a CRANE?

*My neck it extends*

> Mechanical cranes have long horizontal 'necks' which can sometimes extend and retract as needed.

*and sometimes it bends down into the water or up to the sky.*

> The birds called cranes have long necks and can be found near water or in the sky.

*In cities many consider me friends.*

> This is the mechanical crane again.

*With long slender legs, so graceful am I.*

> Avian cranes have long slender legs and are graceful. Mechanical cranes have a long slender tower and sometimes move gracefully.

The hint refers to (thanks to the OP for clarifying):

> [Ichabod Crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichabod_Crane), who flees from a Headless Horseman in Washington Irving's *The Legend of Sleepy Hollow*.

Comment: gah, I deleted my comment by accident, but yes this is the answer! I went back and accepted user1566694's answer because they got it a teensy bit sooner, but you both figured it out super fast!

Answer (score 0):

> A selfie stick

My neck it extends and sometimes it bends down into the water or up to the sky.

> It extends and can reach places where it's difficult like in water and can be bent to put in places.

In cities many consider me friends. With long slender legs, so graceful am I.

> People take a lot of selfies, so keep it close to them. It's thin and slender. They are so small that you can put it in pocket and they don't even come in your way.

EDIT : it doesn't go well with the hint though.

Comment: very clever answer, but it doesn't really go with the legs part, or the water bit (hopefully you wouldn't extend your selfie stick down into the water! you'd ruin your phone!)

Comment: Go-pros exist so you wont ruin your phone :D